# ¿Por que no puedo cerrar la ventana cuando valido TextBox con ErrorProvider en C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo unas validaciones en C# con ErrorProvider.

Las validaciones son a unos `TextBox`.

```
 //Llama al método valida para decidir si el TextBox está vacío.
 private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
 {
     valida(sender, e, textBox1, errorProvider1);
 }

 //Método que recibe un textbox y un Error provider para validar si el textBox esta vacio.
 private void valida(object sender, CancelEventArgs e, TextBox tb, ErrorProvider error)
  {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
      {
          e.Cancel = true;
          error.SetError(tb, "Campos Vacios");
      }
  }

 //valida cuando el TextBox pierde el foco y quita el ErrorProvider si no está vacío
 private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "");
 }

 //Cerrar ventana
 private void btnCerrar(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.Close();
 }
```

El problema lo tengo cuando el `ErrorProvider` se activa por así decirlo. Si el `TextBox` que estoy validando esta vacio muestra el `ErrorProvider`, y el cursor se queda en ese `TextBox` vacío esperando a ser validado otra vez.

Pero:

> ¿Porque no puedo cerrar la ventana cuando `ErrorProvider` está activo?
>
> ¿Porque no puedo dar Tab o cambiar el cursor mientras `ErrorProvider` está activo?

Es una aplicación de escritorio hecha en C#.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el formulario tiene ese signo de error no puedo cambiar el cursor, mucho menos cerrar la ventana.

**EDIT:**

Si quito el `e.cancel = true;` no me muestra el ErrorProvider

**EDIT2**
En el evento `Form1_FormClosing` del form hice lo que me dijo @JLPrieto `e.cancel = false;` lo cual funciona solo cunado se presiona la X del form y cierra el formulario. Pero si lo hago desde el button1 `this.close()` no cierra la ventana cuando presiono el botón.

Comment: e.Cancel = true; no hace lio?

Comment: Si lo comento no valida si esta vacio.

Comment: no sale el error provider?

Comment: Correcto, no sale el errorProvider

Comment: @LuisFernando, mira este [enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23e775b2-9974-4c92-970a-710b7fd803f2/i-need-to-remove-all-errorproviders-from-the-form-?forum=csharplanguage). Si entendí bien, tienes que establecer un valor al errorProvider.

Comment: Si lo tengo seteado.             error.SetError(tb, "Campos Vacios"); Si te fijas Valida recibe como parametro el ErrorProvider

Comment: El evento Validating se produce cuando el control pierde el foco. En el método asignado a este evento podremos determinar si el contenido del control es válido, según los criterios que se establezcan. Si el contenido no es válido podemos cancelar el evento y devolver el foco al control estableciendo la propiedad Cancel, del parámetro CancelEventArgs del controlador de eventos, en true, en cuyo caso se suspenden todos los eventos que normalmente se producirían después del evento Validating. En la práctica, el usuario no puede abandonar el control hasta que los datos son válidos.

Comment: Si la prueba nos confirma la validez de los datos, se termina la validación y se genera el evento Validated. Ahora podremos usar el dato, pues lo consideramos correcto.

Comment: Entiendo que el foco de pone en el  textbox del error esperando a que introduzcan valores correctos por asi decirlo, pero lo que quiero hacer es que si el usuario ya no quiere hacer esa accion se le permita cerrar la ventana. Pero ese es el problema que no le permite cerrar la ventana. @JLPrieto

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner en el evento FormClosing del formulario e.Cancel = false?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que `e.Cancel` cuando se establece en true, cancela cualquier evento que se produzca despues de `Validating` que en este caso serían `FormClosing` y `KeyPress`, lo cual impide que se cierre el formulario o que cambie el foco a otro control

Comment: Si quitas `e.Cancel` el error provider se muestra, pero no se ve ya que el formulario se cierra a la vez que se muestra el error y con e.Cancel si se muestra porque se impide que se cierre el formulario

Comment: Gracias Héctor por tu aporte, estaba con una validación en C# y queria que por cualquier causa al pulsar en un boton "cancelar" se borraran todos los erroProvider, no estaba consiguiendo hasta ver tu respuesta. Repito, muchas gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bien, el problema aquí es que la propiedad `Cancel` de `CancelEventArgs` cuando se establece en `true`, siempre bloquerá cualquier evento que se produzca después del evento `Validating`.

En este caso, los eventos en conflicto son `Form.FormClosing`, `Button.Click` y `KeyPress` que impide que seselccione el siguiente control con `Tab`, puesto que estuve realizando pruebas con tu código y efectivamente, el evento `Click` de tu botón cancelar nunca se ejecuta (Probé con un MessageBox), tampoco el evento `FormClosing`.

La solución?

Usar la [Propiedad Control.CausesValidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx), es un booleano que obtiene o establece un valor que indica si el control hace que se realice una validación de todos los controles que requieren validación cuando reciben el foco.

Entonces en tu caso sería así:

```
textBox1.CausesValidation = false;
```

Y es que si la propiedad `CausesValidation` se establece en `false`, los eventos `Validating` y `Validated` se suprimen.

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);

        //Llamo a esta propiedad aquí porque este evento se ejecuta antes de Validating
        textBox1.CausesValidation = false;
    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Valida(sender, e, errorProvider1);
    }

    private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Borra todos los valores de configuración asociados con ErrorProvider
        errorProvider1.Clear();
    }

    private void Valida(object sender, CancelEventArgs e, ErrorProvider error)
    {
        // El objeto sender, hace referencia al control que llama al evento;
        // en resumen, puedes convertir implicitamente el objeto sender en Control (TextBox en este caso)
        var tb = ((TextBox)sender);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
        {
            error.SetError(tb, "Campos Vacios");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Bien, he desarrollado un bloque de código que te puede ser útil, elimina los eventos `Validating` y `Validated` y pon esto en tu `Form_Load`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    //Se produce cuando el control pierde el foco
    textBox1.LostFocus += (s, e) =>
    {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Campos vacios");
         else errorProvider1.Clear();
    };

    //Se produce cuando el control recibe el foco
    textBox1.GotFocus += (s, e) =>
    {

    };
}
```

Si, los eventos `GotFocus` y `LostFocus` están deprecated (discontinuados), pero todavía hay casos en los que se pueden usar; si lo que quieres es algo moderno, entonces necesitas los eventos `Enter` y `Leave`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
     //Se produce cuando el control pierde el foco
     textBox1.Leave += (s, e) =>
     {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Campos vacios");
          else errorProvider1.Clear();
     };

     //Se produce cuando el control recibe el foco
     textBox1.Enter += (s, e) =>
     {

     };
 }
```

Comment: Estaba leyendo sobre GotFocus y LostFocus y estan deprecated.

Comment: [Mira esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355140/cant-find-gotfocus-lostfocus-in-my-user-control) fijate en la respuesta aceptada

Comment: @LuisFernando Cometi un error, estaba tan emocionado contestando tu pregunta que me olvide que GotFocus y LostFocus fueron reemplazados por Enter y Leave, pero, me gustaria saber, porque desmarcaste mi respuesta a pesar de que la corregi?

Comment: @LuisFernando Ten en cuenta que nadie te habia contestado en 1 mes, ademas, si respondi a tu pregunta puesto que te mostre la forma de hacerlo simplificando tu codigo

Comment: @LuisFernando Es verdad que use eventos anticuados, puesto que en el momento de responder, no recorde a Enter y Leave, pero, para eso se editan las respuestas. Piensalo, inverti tiempo y esfuerzo pars ayudarte con tu problema, cometi un error, pero rectifique, y mi respuesta es la unica que hay.
Si estas molesto por mi error, ten en cuenta que te ayude a resolver tu problema.